# constructor with parameters in UML class diagram

Tags: class, uml, structure, diagram, class-diagram

How would you create an uml class diagram for constructors with parameters?

For default constructors (no parameters) you do

- `policyholder()` for the diagram and in the pseudo-code

For constructors with parameters would you do the same thing:

- `policyholder (policynumber, service class, and customer age)` for class diagrams and pseudo-code.

It also asked to initialize each attribute to value where an object of this type can be instantiated. If a policy number is not between 1000 and 999 inclusive, then set the policy number to 0. (policy number is attribute)

Answer (score 133):

The common way is to write constructors like methods and simply omit the return type.

[image]

If you want to be extra clear, you can add `<<constructor>>` in front.

Comment: UML can be sometimes a nitpickers dream, I found out that it's actually `<<Create>>`, see [UML 2.5.1](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) page 198 (PDF-page number 240)

Comment: @Ciantic The page numbering is still right, but the document moved to https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Page 195/745 now :)

Comment: 237/796 using the PDF controls. In the middle of section **11.4.4 Notation**.